# Google sheets - link chart to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I don't know if it is possible but I want to link a chart in google sheets to another sheet. I know that you can use

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=12345";"Link to sheet")
```

in cells, but is something like this also possible for charts?

Comment: charts cant be referenced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at the time of this answer you cannot reference a chart from one sheet to another like you would do with sheets using `HYPERLINK`.

### Workaround

A way to solve this issue is to select your chart and in the three dots for options select **Move to own sheet**. This will create a new sheet with the chart as its only content allowing you to then [link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en) to the chart using the new sheet reference.

Let me know if this workaround fits your situation or if you would need other type of workaround.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: i actually decided to do something completely different instead but I will still accept this answer.